# Google Course Builder - How to login using Gitkit or Firebase?

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, gitkit

I am trying to configure Google Course Builder to use Gitkit for Google account and email \ password login.

I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/pabloppp/Course-Builder-gitkit-setup-guide) created for version 1.9 of course builder and I received a 400 error page after type user and password or login with Google account. I am using version 1.10 of Google Course Builder and after tying a lot, could not make it work with Gitkit.

[Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) support would be amazing for Google Course Builder as Gitkit will probably be replaced in the future.

Does anyone here had success configuring Google Course Builder and [Gitkit](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/)? And about Firebase? It is possible to use it with Google Course Builder? How?

After login with an (non-Google) email account, I got 400 error at this URL:
https://cursos-mundo-da-eletrica.appspot.com/modules/gitkit/signin?signInSuccessUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fcursos-mundo-da-eletrica.appspot.com%2Fsample-course-2%2Fregister

And logging with Google account, a 400 error on this URL:
https://cursos-mundo-da-eletrica.appspot.com/modules/gitkit/signin?signInSuccessUrl=%2F

Any ideias? Is there official support for Firebase in Google Course Builder? The Gitkit implementation were fully tested in 1.10?